# prevent user from submitting form

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, wordpress

I have my website in which I have **email pdf** functionality

**Procedure is :**

- when user enters email and then he has to click on submit button
- after clicking submit button , form will not submit and form will hide and
- there is another hidden div contains **thank you message** which appears with **Ok button**.
- When User Click on **OK button** then form will submit.

***But Now the Problem is :***

When User enter email and if he press **ENTER** accidentally then form gets submitted without showing thank you message.

I want to Disable **ENTER** when user Press **Enter** key.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp

Comment: @Robuust That's not a good recommendation. The implicit `eval`, the lack of separation of concerns...

Comment: [Disable ENTER when user Press Enter key](https://www.google.com/search?q=Disable+ENTER+when+user+Press+Enter+key&oq=Disable+ENTER+when+user+Press+Enter+key&sugexp=chrome,mod=11&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Did you do some RnD... see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794017/disable-form-submission-via-enter-key-on-only-some-fields) & [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter) & [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235622/jquery-disable-form-submit-on-enter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code, will surely work for you:

```
var class = $('.classname');
function stopRKey(evt) {
var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text")) {return false;}
}

class.onkeypress = stopRKey;
```

Comment: I don't like `document.onkeypress = ...`; First, perhaps you shouldn't stop _all_ enter keys. second, this will overwrite any previous event handlers. Use `addEventListener` or jQuery (especially since it's available).

Answer (score 4):

Check which key was pressed ant if was the enter key return false. Using jQuery this is easy.

```
var field = $('.classname');

field.keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which==13){
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Now it looks much better. Note that `on("keydown", ...` is also a possibility (and much more consistent with other events).

Comment: @InGodITrust it is stopping my all keypress events .

Comment: @Surinder It should only stop the `enter` key

Comment: @Surinder do you have jquery loaded?

Comment: @InGodITrust I was assuming so. It's tagged as such.

Comment: @JanDvorak but i cant imagine what else the problem could be

Comment: @InGodITrust I was assuming so. No longer I am.

Comment: Now the problem solved . i tried the above code  that works for me  thank you for help :)

Answer (score 3):

you can try this to disable the submit on keypress

```
$(function() {

    $("form").on("keypress", function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) return false;
      });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular html button instead of a submit button. In the onclick event of the button write some Javascript to show/hide the DIV. The button on the Thank You DIV make that a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Place this in the script:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function TriggeredKey(e)
{
    var keycode;
    if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
    if (window.event.keyCode == 13 ) return false;
}
</script>
```